# Custom widget, blur 2 widgets with text on front

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I made my own widget with blur, bottom widget is looking correct, but top isn't. On top widget, text is behind blur, but why?
I need same result like second widget. (Text front of blur)
Second widget is looking correct.
Please look screenshot at first.
How to fix it? Thanks for any help.

[image: Screenshot]

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          // incorrect
          MyCard(
            imageLink:
                'https://catherineasquithgallery.com/uploads/posts/2021-02/1612198837_120-p-fioletovii-fon-mainkraft-160.png',
            text: 'AR-scene',
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 70,
          ),
          //correct
          MyCard(
            imageLink:
                'https://www.digiseller.ru/preview/1019450/p1_3193057_f7ad4eea.jpg',
            text: 'Photos',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// my custom widget
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final imageLink;
  final text;
  const MyCard({Key? key, required this.imageLink, required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 270,
      height: 320,
      child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 4, sigmaY: 3),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          )),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
          image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover, image: NetworkImage(imageLink))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `BackdropFilter` with `ClipRect`, else it covers the covering the full screen.

```dart
  return Container(
      key: ValueKey(text),
      width: 270,
      height: 320,
      child: ClipRect( //<- here
        child: BackdropFilter(
```

More on [BackdropFilter-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html)

Comment: Also you can play with [ImageFilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using backdrop filter applies that particular filter to the whole screen. You can use ClipRRect to make it adopt the size of child widget (Container in this case).

```
// my custom widget
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final imageLink;
  final text;
  const MyCard({Key? key, required this.imageLink, required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      child: Container(
        width: 270,
        height: 320,
        child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 4, sigmaY: 3),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover, image: NetworkImage(imageLink))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use `ImageFiltered` instead of `BackdropFilter` widget.

`ImageFiltered` blurs its child, for example, a single picture.

`BackdropFilter` blurs everything "behind" it, but does not blur its own child. It's useful in situations like a pop-up dialog, where you want to blur the whole screen, except the dialog itself.